# Jenkins not triggered by github-webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have taken these steps:

- Check "GitHub project" and set up the project
- Check "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"
- Setup connection to private repository with user/password
- If I build manually, it works
- In GitHub, create a webhook on push to http://my_jenkins_url/github-webhook/
- Whenever I commit something, it shows that a webhook has been sent and I get a 200 response code (on github)

But no build is triggered on Jenkins. The GitHub Hook Log says: "Polling has not run yet.". How can I make it "start"? How can I further debug this?

EDIT: I have not added a GitHub Server in Manage Jenkins -> Configure -> GitHub since I ran into issue with the authentication (but that would be a different question). Is this required for github webhooks?

EDIT2: I figured out how to add a GitHub API to the Jenkins config (using Personal Access Token with git hook access enabled). But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I hope youre not running Jenkins as local host? Then it wont work. I know I'm not supposed to post links but here is a very easy blogpost on one of the easiset way to implement webhooks. For me it worked like a charm.

https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Stuck to solve Skipped {ProjectName} because it doesn't have a matching repository.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found how to fix it properly.

**First**. set Jenkins logger at Jenkins manage > system log

add log recoder, with this configuration

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitStatus - All
com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook - All
org.jenkinsci.plugins.github - All
```

**Second**. Hook trigger again.

and check logger again. In my case, the logger says

```
Skipped {ProjectName} because it doesn't have a matching repository.
```

**Third**. Check the webhook url where the webhook request exactly came from.

it will be specified at logger like this:

```
Received PushEvent for https://github.com/{username}/{reponame} from {ip} ⇒ http://{your jenkins url}/github-webhook/
```

**Fourth**. Again go to jenkins project configuration,

check whole github urls are exactly same as https://github.com/{username}/{reponame} at step 3.

No .git at last.

I hope this answer helps you. Thank you

Comment: This is the best way to debug webhooks. Jenkins jobs are required to run at least once manually before triggered by webhook.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally fixed my Jenkins-Github webhook.

Comment: @blue-hope where is the project configuration in the job? I have "GitHub Project" and "SCM" two places