# Jenkins Not triggering after git webhook

Tags: git, github, jenkins

When I commit code to a branch <#dev> Jenkins receives the appropriate webhook trigger from Github, but I get the error `Skipped {Project} because it doesn't have a matching repository.`

After August 13th I was forced to convert all the jobs to SSH and since then the jobs havent been triggering.

Ive tried specifying using the ssh (git@github.com//) web url, the https (https://github.com//) web url and the ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443 (after adapting my config - this is how i was able to build after setting up RSA) url in both the trigger and project sections of the configuration

Ive setup a logger in Jenkins for Github webhooks and the hook is registering with Jenkins, but not triggering the job.

[Logging with this setup, found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714213/jenkins-not-triggered-by-github-webhook)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> After August 13th I was forced to convert all the jobs to SSH and since then the jobs havent been triggering.

Then convert them back to HTTPS.

Just make sure to register in Jenkins a [token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of a GitHub account user password (which is no longer authorized).

Comment: is this working for you? because im getting the error that git changed their policy blah blah and i can't continue from there.

Comment: @rcpilotp51 It does. That error is linked to HTTPS URL which are not using a PAT (Personal Access Token) as a password. Can you check the credentials used for those SCM in your Jenkins jobs?

Comment: thanks for your help. It seems to me working for my non-pipeline (groovy) jobs, but not for the latter. i created a credential for the PAT and am using the credentialID in the pipeline, but the job doesnt trigger. any suggestions on that?

Comment: @rcpilotp51 No suggestion on the top of my head. Maybe those pipelines are not using the same credentials?